# SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild Scans Files Twice

Tags: c#, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services and SonarQube tasks 'SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis (new)' and 'SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis (new)'.

I have a project with C#- and JavaScript -sources and I want them both analyzed. I'v set the sources directory to the 'Root' (see folder structure) and everything seems to be working except one minor detail. The scanner scans the CSharpSources with subdirectories AND the subdirectories separately. This leads to an error that a file cannot be indexed twice.

Folder structure

```
Root
  CSharpSources
    Project1
    Project2
  JavaScriptSources
```

The scanner scans all my project directories separately, but then also scans the CSharpSources-directory with the subdirectories which leads to problems.

Is there a way I can prevent this with include/exclude sources settings or what is the suggested way?

I've tried NOT setting the sources directory and the analysis works, but it only analyses C# files, not the JavaScript-files. Setting the source to the Root-directory, includes also the JavaScript-files. If there is a better way to include them without running into this indexing issue, I'd love to hear it.

I can see the issue from the SonarQube task logs where I have this kind of entries:

```
INFO: -------------  Scan Project1
  ...
INFO: -------------  Scan Project2
  ...
INFO: -------------  Scan CSharpSources
  ...
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: File ... can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I already have verbose logging enabled and can see some debug-entries in the log. Not sure where exactly I would put the -X switch and if I could see some more details?

Comment: Which scanner are you using for analysis?

Comment: Set the system.debug to true then queue build and share the log on the OneDrive (remove personal information).

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam the VSTS task uses 'SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "sonar.sources" from your configuration file (Sonar.Analysis.xml) as it automatically detects it from your .NET solution. This can prevent same files indexed twice. And again in the same file, you can define your inclusions and exclusions. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters